# Data model schema that supports oplog

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to implement a survey app with Meteor. My first thought for data modelling was this:

Submissions collection where I would collect answers:

```
{
  formId: "........",
  values: [
    {question: "What is your name?", answer:"Aykut Yaman"},
    {question: "How old..?", answer:"7"},
    {question: "Hobbies?", answer: ["Kitap Okumak", "Spor Yapmak"]},
    {question: "Foo", answer: "Lorem ipsum ..."}
  ]
}
```

Then I would query the collection like this, in order to find out surveys, how has given a particular answer to some question:

```
submissions.find({$and: [{"values.answer": "7"}, {"values.question": "How old..?"}]})
```

Then I realised that this query [is not correct](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/05/27/using-elemmatch-in-a-mongodb-query.aspx), that I have to use `$elemMatch`. But it seems that `$elemMatch` is an [unsupported projection](https://kadira.io/academy/optimize-your-app-for-oplog/) in Meteor.

How do I have to change my query or collection in order to use oplog, and have my collection simple?

Comment: Not clear how the [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) comes into play here. If your MongoDB deployment is backed by a replica set, any operations that add/update/delete data will be saved to the oplog on the primary so secondaries can copy & apply these operations.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer model would be to split the answers from the questions:

```
{
  formId: "idOfForm",
  values: [
    {_id: "id1", question: "What is your name?"},
    {_id: "id2", question: "How old..?", answer:"7"},
    {_id: "id3", question: "Hobbies?", answer: ["Kitap Okumak", "Spor Yapmak"]},
    {_id: "id4", question: "Foo", answer: "Lorem ipsum ..."}
  ]
}
```

and in the Answers collection

```
{_id: "answer1", formId: "idOfForm", questionId: "id1", answer:"Aykut Yaman"}
... and so on
```

this would give you the added benefit of saving some disk space as you do not store the question for each answer. You don't have to store the `formId` for each answer but it might improve the performance for querying the forms.